# Проблемы настройки Vagrantfile

Tags: windows, docker, vagrant

## Что есть:

- есть *Vagrantfile*

  ```
  Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    config.vm.box = "dduportal/boot2docker"
    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080
    config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.56.101"
    config.vm.provision :docker do |d|
      d.build_image "/vagrant", args: "-t 'test_site'"
      d.run "test_site",
       args: "-p 80:80 -v '/vagrant:/var/www/test_site'",
       daemonize: true
    end
  end
  ```
- есть *Dockerfile*, в котором подымается **ubunta**, устанавливается *php+mysql* и открываются порты `EXPOSE 80 8080 443 3306 22`.

## Проблемы:

- после **vagrant up** запускается *dduportal/boot2docker*, но **docker build** не происходит;
- после запуска **vagrant provision** запускается **docker build** (успешно), но не запускается **docker run**;
- после **vagrant reload** запускается **docker run**, но сразу завершается (проверял **docker ps** контейнера нету, а **docker ps -a** контейнер есть, но уже не работает).

## Цели:

- одной командой **vagrant up** устанавливался билд;
- синхронизация папок **windows** через **dduportal/boot2docker** в **ubuntu** (для ide).

## Дополнительное:

- все попытки использовать нативные способы vagrant для работы с docker в виндовсе неудобны, а конкретно секция provider docker в vagrantfile приводит либо к ошибкам, либо к тому, что синхронизация папок доступна только через rsync (даже заставив работать на windows rsync, появились еще уйма проблем), поэтому отказался от этого способа вообще;
- не разобрался, как в момент docker build использовать папки из dduportal/boot2docker без явного копирвания, то есть в папке /var/www/test_site должен лежать код из windows, чтобы запустился composer install, но залинковать папки можно только при docker run, и поэтому приходится заходить в контейре и запускать вручную composer install;
- использую именно **dduportal/boot2docker**, потому что другие boot2docker автоматически хотят запустить provider docker, который я не могу использовать.

## Итого

Хотел бы получить совет, как можно реализовать мои цели, или примеры, как Вы добились похожих целей.

Comment: господи tsya.ru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> есть Dockerfile в котором подымаеться ubunta и устанавливаеться php+mysql и открываются порты EXPOSE 80 8080 443 3306 22

Возникает вопрос, а нужен ли вам вообще докер? Смотрите:

1. Концепция докера подразумевает один сервис в контейнере. Это сделано специально, чтобы обеспечить легкое разбитие приложений на отдельные независимые контейнеры (mysql, php-fpm, nginx, какой-нибудь redis), которые линкуются как угодно и поддерживаются отдельно друг от друга. Сам принцип докера в том, что есть некий image, и нам наплевать, что в нем внутри - нам не наплевать, что он предоставляет и что поднимается ровно за одну команду. Есть куча разных image для mysql, но все они занимаются одним и тем же, и большинство из них взаимозаменяемы.
2. Насколько понял, вам нужна изоляция проекта. Зачем дополнительно разворачивать докер в вагранте, если вагрант уже сам по себе некисло так изолирует?

> после vagrant reload запускаеться docker run но сразу завершаеться

Скорее всего проблема в самом докерфайле. Как только завершается cmd/entrypoint - контейнер останавливается, я думаю, тут именно этот случай.

> не разобрался как в момент docker build использовать папки из dduportal/boot2docker без явного копирвания,

Никак. Докер либо копирует файлы-папки в момент билда, либо они явно подключаются в момент создания контейнера. Иначе перенесенный контейнер может не заработать, а это рушит всю концепцию докера.

Comment: 1. Концепцию как раз хочу осознать на реальном проекте, и я планировал, что я разобью на несколько независимых контейнеров, залинкую и одновремено запущую несколько. Но это все потом, сейчас простые вещи хотел.
2. Мне нужна не изоляция, а быстрый девелоперский деплой одного сервера и пару клиентов.
3. То есть в cmd нужно визывать, например, mysql процесс, хотя я рассчитывал, что опция daemonize: true заставит его не останавливаться.

Comment: @duhon, вы больше времени потратите на запихивание всего в один докерфайл, чем если сразу все будете делать по-чистому. Посмотрите docker-compose, контейнеры нужных вам сервисов уже готовы, надо только отнаследоваться и написать пару строчек. Daemonize просто запустит контейнер в бекграундном режиме, это никак не управляет его внутренностями. Да, CMD должен выполняться все время жизни контейнера.

Вам вообще не нужн вагрант, разверните обычную убунту в виртуалбоксе и поставьте туда докер.

Ради всего святого, посмотрите **хотя бы** правила тся/ться.